# Mongo DB Lookup with condition based on the third table

Tags: mongodb

**1) mentor Table**
[image]
**2) student Table**
[image]
**3) mentor_students Table**
[image]
need the query to list students based on mentor by passing mentor id to the table mentor_students

Comment: Can you provide example documents of all 3 collections, and expected output?

Comment: hi @NeNaD, sure will update now

Comment: hi @NeNaD updated with screenshots now, output will be like mentor with students array.
let me know if the above okay, usually i can do a join query in mysql but not here cause am new to MongoDB

Comment: anyone here to solve this problem?